# ServiceNow Add Button to Sys_popup View

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

We need to implement a verify PIN option for when user's call our service desk. I'd like to add a new button to the sys_popup view of sys_user, the popup profile dialogue box, that pops up when you click on the info (i) button beside the user name, which would be on the New Call form (new_call.do) - see mock up image below. However, I've been told that it's not possible to add a new button to this Sys_popup view.

The alternative I've been given is that agents would need to click on the 'Open Record' button, which would then open another tab to the main user profile page (sys_user.do) and then have a button there. This isn't idle for the service desk agents, as it takes them away from the new call form, where they raise the tickets, as well as adding additional clicks and steps to their process!

Is it possible to add a new button to the sys_popup view?

[Sys_popup Mock Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm6d2.png)